# grid 960 - while executing inspectSection in dmx960 grid, js error occurred.

Tags: javascript, html, grid, runtime-error

I'm trying to run this grid extention in DW CS5. I'm a front end person so debugging other people's code isn't my thing. So when I try set the grid precepts I get this error:

```
while executing inspectSection in dmx960 grid, js error occurred.
```

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Barefoot Development Group</title>
<link href="CSS/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="CSS/text.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="CSS/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>


<body>
<!------start container------->

<div id = "container" class ="container_16"></div>
    <div id = "social_search" class = "grid_16"></div>
      <div id = "social_links" class = "grid_1 alpha"></div>





<!------Main container-------->



<!------Header start---------->

<!------Social Links---------->



<!-------End social links------> 


<!----start Social icons -------->


<!----end social icons----->

</body>
</html>
```

I tried deleting the cache in Config folder and reinstalling the extension. Didn't work. I checked the log files and found this:

> JS Error:     theElem.getAttribute is not a function  filename:
>   C:\Users\cvr\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Dreamweaver
>   CS5\en_US\Configuration\Shared\DMXzone\960 Grid\dmx960grid_lib.js
>     lineno: 598

So I went to the JS file and here is what I found in this expression block:

```
function getGridClassNum(theElem) {
    if (!theElem) return 0;
    var cls = theElem.getAttribute("class");
    if (!cls) return 0;
    if (cls == 'clearfix') {
        //Try to read the parent
    var parent = getGridElement(theElem.parentNode);
    if (parent && parent.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        return getGridClassNum(parent);
    }       
    } else {
      var numMatch  = cls.match(new RegExp("\\b(grid|container)_(\\d+)\\b"));
      if (numMatch && numMatch.length > 1) {
        return parseFloat(numMatch[2]);
        //      //decrease with prefix and suffix       
        //  - getGridClassNameNum(theElem, 'prefix') 
        //      - getGridClassNameNum(theElem, 'suffix');
      }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't see anything particularly amiss here. But perhaps a more expert debugger can tell me if there is something going on here. Here is what confuses me - I was looking for the function *inspectSection* but I couldn't find it. I'm left scratching my head here.

Could this be a problem of including the script directly into the html doc?

Thanks!